# DCOM session moniker

Tags: windows, session, process, dcom, opc

The code is in my OPC Client, and I want to activate a DCOM OPC Server. My purpose is to activate the OPC Server in session 1, but it works out still in session 0, i mean the OPC Server process is still run in session 0. Because the OPC Server depends on some other process in session 1, so it can't works in session 0. Can anybody helps me? It troubles my for days.

```
IBindCtx* pBindCtx;
HRESULT hr = CreateBindCtx(NULL, &pBindCtx);

BIND_OPTS2 stBindOpt;
ZeroMemory(&stBindOpt,sizeof(BIND_OPTS2));
stBindOpt.cbStruct = sizeof(BIND_OPTS2);
hr = pBindCtx->GetBindOptions(&stBindOpt);
stBindOpt.dwClassContext = CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER;
stBindOpt.grfFlags = BIND_JUSTTESTEXISTENCE;
stBindOpt.pServerInfo = &tCoServerInfo;
hr  = pBindCtx->SetBindOptions(&stBindOpt);

if (FAILED(hr)) exit(0);  // Handle errors here.

WCHAR wszCLSID[64];
StringFromGUID2(clsid, wszCLSID, 64);
CString strCLSID = wszCLSID;
strCLSID.Replace(_T("{"), _T(""));
strCLSID.Replace(_T("}"), _T(""));

CString strMoniker;
strMoniker.Format(_T("Session:1!clsid:%s"), strCLSID);
CLogger::Instance().WriteLog(_T("Moniker String:") + strMoniker);

nSize = strMoniker.GetLength() * sizeof(WCHAR);
LPWSTR wstrMoniker = new WCHAR[nSize];
// Copy the machine name string into the server info structure:
#ifdef _UNICODE
lstrcpyn(wstrMoniker, strMoniker, nSize);
#else 
mbstowcs(wstrMoniker, strMoniker, nSize);
#endif//_UNICODE

ULONG ulParsed;
IMoniker* pMoniker;
hr = MkParseDisplayNameEx(pBindCtx,
wstrMoniker,
&ulParsed,
&pMoniker
);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
IUnknown* pSessionTestFactory;
hr = pMoniker->BindToObject(pBindCtx,
            NULL,
            IID_IUnknown,
            (void**)&pSessionTestFactory
            );
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    pMoniker->AddRef();
}

pSessionTestFactory->Release();
}

pMoniker->Release();
delete [] wstrMoniker;
```

Comment: btw delete [] on wstrMoniker is incorrect, wstrMoniker is not an array and its on the stack

Comment: i dont remember ever doing it so complicated when accessing a remote opc server, normally if you have the opc server registered on your client it should be like accessing a local opc server.

Comment: Thanks! Remote machine name is required when connect to a remote OPC Server, then use the OPCEUM process to get CLSID of the remote OPC Server, and finally BindToObject is called. What I want to know is how to create a OPC Server process on a specific widows session.